# NullPointerException cannot invoke method of null object

Tags: spring, jpa, spock

I am trying to write a simple test, that will test all my crud operations using a `service` the problem is that I do not know why I am getting this error and I am not able even to run a single test.

```
@SpringBootTest
class EpisodeServiceTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private EpisodeService episodeService

    def "should create episode and save in in the database"() {
        when:
        Episode episode = new Episode("title", "description")

        and:
        episodeService.addEpisode(episode)

        then:
        episode == episodeService.findById(episode.id)
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EpisodeService {

    private EpisodeRepository episodeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public EpisodeService(EpisodeRepository episodeRepository) {
        this.episodeRepository = episodeRepository;
    }

    public Episode findById(long id) {
        return episodeRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public List<Episode> findAll() {
        return episodeRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void addEpisode(Episode episode) {
        if (episode != null)
            episodeRepository.save(episode);
    }

    public void deleteEpisodeById(long id) {
        Episode episode = findById(id);
        if (episode != null)
            episodeRepository.delete(episode);
    }
}
```

The repository is just a simple repository that extends `JpaRepository` and my question is how to use spock to test jpa entities? What I am doing wrong, because I am trying to do that for the first time, earlier I wrote a simple tests in JUnit but I wanted to try spock.

Comment: Provide an information about `EpisodeRepository` declaration and configuration. What the datasource was configured for tests?

Comment: @Mark as I mentioned above the EpisodeRepository is a simple interface that extends JpaRepository<Episode, Long> and nothing more. Datasource is in the docker-compose and it is just a normal MySQL.

Comment: Can you please provide the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli the exception in the stacktrace is just `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method addEpisode() on null object`  and of course where in the code it is, so it is line 18 and that is the addEpisode method. Nothing more.

Comment: Please provide a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there are too many variables in this problem without it, too much speculation. The problem could be in the repository class or in the episode class (e.g. in its `equals` method). If nobody can reproduce your problem, answers are just more or less educated guesses. Most of your fellow programmers like to analyse, not to guess, though.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for it was to add this dependency into maven

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

It was not enough to add just the `spock-core`.

Answer (score 0):

Your test class is missing the annotation `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class EpisodeServiceTest extends Specification {
```

Comment: `@RunWith` annotation is unnecessary here, the `@SpringBootTest` annotation is definitely enough because the test now are passing when they should.